# how to prove the convexity of the real part of this formula

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics

The formula is as
${{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} \left( {{\bf{q}}_{k(l)}^H{\bf{H}}_k^H{z_{k,l}}} \right)}$. The variable is ${{\bf{q}}_{k,l}} \in {C^{N \times 1}}$.  ${\bf{H}}_k \in {C^{M \times N}}$ and ${{z_{k,l}}} \in {C^{M \times 1}}$ are constant matrix and vector, respectively.

This formula seems to be concave in the paper that I read, but I cannot prove it. Hoping for help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.
The formula can be written as ${{\bf{q}}_{k(l)}^H{\bf{H}}_k^H}+{{\bf{q}}_{k(l)}}{{\bf{H}}_k}$, which is affine over ${{\bf{q}}_{k(l)}}$, therefore it is convex or concave.